# Migration from Postgresql to SQLite

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I am working on a project which uses PostgreSQL on the backend to handle database. As PostgreSQL has procedural languages i.e. PL/pgSQL support, existing code contains various user defined functions.

Now I want to migrate to SQLite which does not have support for procedural langauges, I think. How can I handle this situation in SQLite and use same code fragment (i.e. functions) different time by just calling it.

Comment: I guess the answer is: you can't use SQLite in this case - or you need to move all those functions into your application and do the processing there.

Comment: Agreed with @a_horse_with_no_name . That's the only option you have.